# Communication between two containers on the same host

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

The idea is simple, I need to send a signal from a container to another one to restart `nginx`.

Connect to the `nginx` container from the first one in `ssh` is a good solution?

Do you have other recommended ways for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend installing `ssh`, `Docker` containers are not virtual machines, And should respect microservices architecture to benefit from many advantages it provides.

In order to send signal from one container to another, **You can use docker API.**

First you need to share `/var/run/docker.sock` between required containers.

```
docker run -d --name control -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <Control Container>
```

to send signal to a container named nginx you can do the following:

```
echo -e "POST /containers/nginx/kill?signal=HUP HTTP/1.0\r\n" | \
nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

**Another option** is using a custom image, with a custom script, that checks nginx config files and if the hash is changed sends reload signal. This way, each time you change config, nginx will automatically  reload, or You can reload manually using comments. these kind of scripts are common among `kubernetes` users. Following is an example:

```
nginx "$@"
oldcksum=`cksum /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

inotifywait -e modify,move,create,delete -mr --timefmt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M' --format '%T' \
/etc/nginx/conf.d/ | while read date time; do

    newcksum=`cksum /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`
    if [ "$newcksum" != "$oldcksum" ]; then
        echo "At ${time} on ${date}, config file update detected."
        oldcksum=$newcksum
        nginx -s reload
    fi

done
```

Don't forget to install `inotifywait` package.

Comment: It's not dangerous to have external entry point to restart nginx ?

Comment: Depends on your environment, There are lots of options, You can share config data there are lots of other options

Comment: The problem is I need to be the root user to restart nginx and if possible, i preferer to not have external entry point.

Comment: added another option

Comment: For you, I need to have a cron task for this ?

Comment: No, Remember Microservices, And docker philosophy, Try to use it as entrypoint.